# Changing LPVOID to const u8*

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++14

I am trying to pass in an `LPVOID` and `DWORD` variables to the `SHA1` hash function, but it only takes in `const u8*` and `u32` types is there any way I could change an `LPVOID` to a `const u8*`

```
LPVOID TempLpbuffer;
DWORD TempdwNumberOfBytesToWrite;
const u8* message_array = TempLpbuffer;
static_cast <const u8*>(*TempLpbuffer);
// Data retrived from WAV file
util_sha1_reset(TempLpbuffer);
```

```
Error: C++ a value of type cannot be assigned to an entity of type
```

Comment: Use [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)`<const u8 *>(TempLpbuffer)`.

Comment: Since `TempLpbuffer` is not a pointer-to-const, I would use `static_cast<u8*>(TempLpbuffer)` instead, and then let the compiler apply the `const` as needed when passing the `u8*` to a `const u8*` parameter.